# How to add pagination functionality to a div using ngFor

Tags: angular, pagination, angular-material, angular7

How to add the pagination functionality to the div.

app.component.html

```
<div>

 <div *ngFor="let clg of colleges$">
  <h3>{{clg.name}}</h3>
 </div>

 <mat-paginator [length]="100" [pageSize]="10" [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 
 100]"></mat-paginator>

</div>
```

Comment: Could you tell me what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I am able to fetch the details from json file and to display them using ngFor. But since i am having a huge amount of data...i would like to add a pagination element to the div...i am using the angular material pagination component. But i am not getting an idea how to add this functionality to the pagination component!

Comment: @LitsonThomas Have added an answer please check

Comment: @LitsonThomas you can check the working example in my answer.

Answer (score 9):

You can use `page` event emitter on `mat-paginator` as `(page)="onPageChange($event)"`

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of currentItemsToShow, let i=index;">
  Hello {{item.name}}
</div>
```

```js
onPageChange($event) {
  this.currentItemsToShow =  this.items.slice($event.pageIndex*$event.pageSize,
  $event.pageIndex*$event.pageSize + $event.pageSize);
}
```

**[Stackblitz Demo showing Customized Paginatior, try changing paginator values](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-paginator-example-customized?file=app/paginator-overview-example.ts)**

Answer (score 4):

```html
<div ngFor="let item of items| slice: (page-1)*pagesize : page*  pagesize; index as i;">
  <div *ngIf="page==1" scope="row">{{i+1}}</div>
  <div scope="row" *ngIf="page>1">{{((page-1)*pagesize)+(i+1)}}</div>
  <div>{{item}}</div>
</div>

<ngb-pagination
  [collectionSize]="totalItems"
  [(page)]="page"
  [(pageSize)]="pagesize"
  [rotate]="true">
</ngb-pagination>
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 1):

You should load the data using lazy loading.

For that what you have to do is first you should get total length of records in json file and set `[length]="totalLength"`. Then the mat-paginator will automatically set pages for you based on totalLength. Then you should load first 10 data, i.e. 0 to 10 and assign it to colleges$. I said 10 because its the `[pageSize]`. If your pageSize was 5 load first 5 data and so on. Then when user clicks on a page number, for example 2 you should call you api and it should return next set of data, i.e. 11 to 20 and assign it to colleges$. Data will automatically be refreshed in the view.

It's better to create an api that will fetch data for you when you pass 2 parameters- offset and limit, which is the page size in your case. There are various methods(functions) in the paginator which will get triggered when pageSize changes or user clicks on a page number

Answer (score 1):

I would use `(page)` of the mat-paginator to get the selected values and then filter or splice array based on the value:

HTML Code:

```
<div *ngFor="let clg of filteredArray">
    <h3>{{clg.name}}</h3>
</div>
<mat-paginator [length]="100" [pageSize]="defaultRecords" [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]" (page)="pageEvent = $event; onPaginateChange($event)">
</mat-paginator>
```

TS Code:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MatPaginator, MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material';
/**
 * @title Paginator
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'paginator-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'paginator-overview-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['paginator-overview-example.css'],
})
export class PaginatorOverviewExample implements OnInit {

  colleges: any[] = [{ name: "1" }, { name: "2" }, { name: "3" }, { name: "4" }, { name: "5" }, { name: "6" }, { name: "7" }, { name: "8" }, { name: "9" }, { name: "10" }, { name: "11" }, { name: "12" }, { name: "13" }];

  filteredArray: any[] = []

  defaultRecords: any = 5;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.filteredArray = this.colleges.slice(0, this.defaultRecords);
  }

  onPaginateChange(data) {
    this.filteredArray = this.colleges.slice(0, data.pageSize);
  }
}
```

[`Working_Demo`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xurger)

Comment: Property 'pageEvent' does not exist

Comment: @PavloKozachuk Try to define `pageEvent :any;` component.ts