# What is the best Angular Material Component to lay out horizontal results?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-table

I am just getting into Angular Material.

Is there a way to use the MatTable Component with all its nice paging and sorting features but lay out the results horizontally three results per row rather then vertical rows.  Or is there another component that is better suited to this.

Or should I just use templating and forget Angular Material for this.

Here is the result layout I am trying to get (minus the broken image links).

[image]

---

Also is there some way to use mat-flex to make the table go horizontal?

Comment: If you're open to use 3rd party component library then I recommend PrimeNG. Specifically take a look at https://primeng.org/dataview. It seems to meet your requirements. It support list and grid layouts

Comment: I wouldn't bother trying to use Angular Material's table, it'll just cause you unnecessary pain. An `*ngFor` would probably serve you a lot better. (But you can still use Angular Material's `Paginator`, even without using the table.

Comment: @EliezerBerlin - That's a good tip.   I didn't realize you could use Paginator without MatTable.  I will look into that.  Maybe layout results in a mat-card or something horizontally 3 results per row and provide pager.

Comment: @Sam Yep! It's absolutely possible to use Paginator on an ordinary `*ngFor`. Something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55390742/how-to-add-pagination-functionality-to-a-div-using-ngfor

Answer (score 2):

MatTable might not be the best fit for this specific layout.

You could achieve your desired layout using CSS and Angular's ngFor directive to loop through your data and create the desired structure. You can create a container that holds each row and within each row, display three items.

```
<div class="horizontal-container">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
    <div class="item" *ngIf="i % 3 === 0">
      <div class="item-inner" *ngFor="let subItem of items.slice(i, i + 3)">
        <!-- Your content for each item goes here -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

Comment: I agree.  I would actually rather just template it out.  But I am blogging a book on Full-Stack development with ASP.Net Core on back-end and Angular on front-end just to give myself a project to do while I learn the technology.  And I just wanted to show how to use it since I show straight forward templating and Bootstrap earlier on.